# Automating adding .tex file content to .Rnw files

Tags: r, latex, tex, sweave, rnw

I use a program to produce a series of .tex files. I then manually copy the contents of the .tex files and add it to a .Rnw file (Sweave, compiled in RStudio IDE). Is there a way to automatically include the contents of .tex files in the .Rnw file such that the .tex files automatically compile and produce pretty text/figures/tables rather than require copying? Something like the below does not appear to produce what I desire when compiled.

```
<<>>=
# file.tex contains the code for a pretty LaTeX table
source("file.tex")
@
```

Answer (score 0):

`source` is wrong, that is for running R code. Instead, if you are using knitr, you can use the `child` tag in a knitr chunk, something like:

```
<<my-child-document, child="file.tex">>=
@
```